# I cannot create pdf file with the messages, !pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file nanummjbae): Font nanummjbae at 720 not found

Tags: pdftex, miktex

I bought a new computer and downloaded Miktex and winedt. I cannot create pdf file from them. I don't know how to solve it. Would you help me? Thanks in advance.

```
Command Line:   pdflatex.exe --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "강의계획서_김찬균.tex"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\user\Desktop\공개강의

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 2.9.7300 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(강의계획서_김찬균.tex
LaTeX2e  patch level 2
L3 programming layer 
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size12.clo"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsmath.sty"
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amstext.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsgen.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsbsy.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsopn.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amscls\amsthm.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\amssymb.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\amsfonts.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\latexsym.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.def"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/cjk-ko\kotex.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/kotex-utf\kotex.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/kotex-utf\kotexutf.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\inputenc.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/plain/kotex-plain\kotexutf-core.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/kotex-utf\lucenc.dfu")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/cjk-ko\kolabels-utf.sty")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdfmode.def")
No file 강의계획서_김찬균.aux.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/nanumtype1\lucnanummj.fd")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/context/base/mkii\supp-pdf.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg\epstopdf-base.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\umsa.fd")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\umsb.fd")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\ulasy.fd") [1{C:/Users/user/AppDat
a/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] [2] [3 ] [4 ] [5 ] [6] [7  ]
[8  ] [9 ] [10  ] [11 ] [12    ] [13] [14 ] [15 ]
[16  ] [17     ] [18 ]
[19 ]
Overfull \hbox (9.49098pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 578--579
[]\OT1/cmr/bx/n/12 Remark. $\OML/cmm/m/it/12 xy$\LUC/nanummj/m/n/12/d3 ?LUC/na
nummj/m/n/12/ba t\LUC/nanummj/m/n/12/c5 ?\LUC/nanummj/m/n/12/b3  \LUC/nanummj/
m/n/12/d5 \ \LUC/nanummj/m/n/12/b0 ?LUC/nanummj/m/n/12/c6 ?LUC/nanummj/m/n/12
/c7 D t\LUC/nanummj/m/n/12/c6 ?LUC/nanummj/m/n/12/d5 X\LUC/nanummj/m/n/12/c9 ?
 \LUC/nanummj/m/n/12/c5 J\LUC/nanummj/m/n/12/b3 T\LUC/nanummj/m/n/12/b7 |\LUC/n
anummj/m/n/12/b3 ?$\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 1$\LUC/nanummj/m/n/12/cc (\LUC/nanummj/m/n/
12/c6 ?LUC/nanummj/m/n/12/c5 ?LUC/nanummj/m/n/12/c1   \LUC/nanummj/m/n/12/c8 
 \LUC/nanummj/m/n/12/c6 ?LUC/nanummj/m/n/12/b4  \LUC/nanummj/m/n/12/b2 ?\OT1/
cmr/m/n/12 Archimedes
[20 ] [21   ]
[22 ] [23 ] [24 ] [25 ] [26 ] [27] [28  ]
[29 ] (강의계획서_김찬균.aux)Trying to make PK font nanummjbae at 720 DPI...
The METFAONT mode is: ljfour
Running miktex-makemf.exe...

Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-makemf.log
Running miktex-ttf2pk.exe...

Sorry, but miktex-makepk did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-makepk.log
 )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file nanummjbae): Font nanummjbae at 720 not found

 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!


_____________________________________________________________________

 PDFTeXify Compilation Report (Pages: 0)

 Errors: 1   Warnings: 1   Bad Boxes: 1
```

---

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem with Miktex update. See https://miktex.org/howto/update-miktex